# How to filter a database table

Tags: sql, database

I have a table in access like this:

[image]

Now what I want is to eliminate the the subcase_id that are closed (with all of their status, not just the row with status closed). How can I do that in Access?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Doesn't  " delete from table where ACTIVITY='Closed' " meet your needs??

Comment: I use <>"Closed" and it shows me also the subcases 123-1 dispatch, 123-1 accepted, 123-2 dispatch, 123-2 accepted, 123-3 dispatch, 123-3 accepted. I want to extract only subcases that doesn't have "Close" in their ACTIVITY column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBCASE_ID FROM YOUR_TABLE 
WHERE SUBCASE_ID NOT IN (SELECT SUBCASE_ID FROM YOUR_TABLE where ACTIVITY='Closed')
```

will work I think. I filter closed subcases first and then take non-filtered ones.

Comment: thank you! I will try later and come with an answer.

Comment: If performance is an issue I can try to come up with a join version of it